# On console.log, ViewChild variable is undefined in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a component that has an `@ViewChild` annotation. One of the functions that I'm trying to test calls the `@ViewChild`'s element for focus. However, when I try to log out the `@ViewChild` variable, it is always `undefined`. I thought `componentFixture.detectChanges()` would initiate the `ElementRef`, but it doesn't seem to.

Is there any way to make it so it isn't `undefined`?

Comment: Would you mind showing some code that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't show your code but, probably u have that undefined because you did your ViewChild like:
`@ViewChild(MySubComponent)` 
instead of

```
@ViewChild('componentref')
```

and then in your template:

```
<my-sub-component #componentref></my-sub-component>
```

and of course you need to init your component with `componentFixture.detectChanges()`

Comment: and how do you reference the mock component in the test its self?

Comment: Try to use testBed.get(ChildComponentName), looking at TestBed api i dont see any other native way. It works for services for sure :) The other way not recommended is to expose @ViewChild to a public property of your test component. But in general im a fan of treating component like a regular class. In that case you make mock components only to satisfy creation of your test component and then forget about them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which version of Angular2 you use and how you initialize your test suite but the `detectChanges` method on the `ComponentFixture` instance is responsible to set such fields.

Here is a sample test that shows this:

```
it('should set testElt', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(MyList).then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture) => {
      expect(componentFixture.componentInstance.testElt).toBeUndefined();

      componentFixture.detectChanges();

      expect(componentFixture.componentInstance.testElt).toBeDefined();
      var testElt = componentFixture.componentInstance.testElt;
      expect(testElt.nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('Some test');
    });
}));
```

See the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/THMBXX?p=preview.